# Проверка корректной загрузки

Tags: javascript, php

Кто сможет подсказать, как на JavaScript или PHP проверить корректность загрузки страницы при выполнении, допустим скрипт генерирует адрес `http://cs10374.vkontakte.ru/u69126676/a_eab3c25c.jpg`, и если страница не загружается или ошибка 404, то скрипт не принимает этот адрес, а если `http://cs10374.vkontakte.ru/u69126676/a_eab3c24c.jpg`, страница загружается, то скрипт сохраняет адрес. Примерно такая работа, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
$urls = array(
    "http://cs10374.vkontakte.ru/u69126676/a_eab3c25c.jpg",
    "http://cs10374.vkontakte.ru/u69126676/a_eab3c24c.jpg",
);

stream_context_set_default( array(
'http' => array(
    'method' => 'HEAD'
)
) );

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $status = get_headers($url);

    if ($status !== FALSE) {
        if (strpos($status[0], "200 OK") !== FALSE) {
            echo $url, " - EXISTS\n";
        }
        else {
            echo $url, " - not exists\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Error request for ", $url, "\n";
    }
}
```

Тут используется `HEAD` запрос, если через `GET` то `stream_context_set_default` убрать

Comment: а если скрипт циклом должен перебрать нужные числа(от 20 до 30 там где менял), то как

Comment: А где вы меняли? В URL? Если подбирать URL, то проще его генерить:

    for ($i = 20; $i <= 30; $i++) {
        $url = sprintf("http://cs10374.vkontakte.ru/u69126676/a_eab3c%02dc.jpg", $i);
        ...
    }

Comment: Вот чего не знаю, того не знаю - с Windows-ом дел не имею.

Касаемо `...` там должно быть `$status = ` и все что в ответе

Comment: Можете написать полный код для схемы 
i01.fsimg.ru/номер аватарки/user_big/A_/A_abc/ID.jpg
ID=A_abcdef
в A_ может быть сколько угодно цифр
Генерировать надо номер аватарки и ID

Comment: А чего здесь писать:

    for ($avatar = 1; $avatar <= последний_номер_аватарки; $avatar++) {
        for ($id = 1000000; $id <= последний_номер_id; $id++) {
            $url = sprintf(
                "http://i01.fsimg.ru/%d/user_big/%s/%s/%d.jpg",
                $avatar,
                substr(strval($id),0,3), # первые 3 цифры номера
                substr(strval($id),0,5), # нервые 5 цифр номера
                $id # номер полностью
            );
        }
    }

Comment: Там с проверкой? И еще надписи первые 3 цифры номера, первые 5 цифр номера и номер полностью надо заменять чем-нибудь?, кстати номер аватарки и id не совпадают<?php
   for ($avatar = 1; $avatar <= 1000; $avatar++) {
    for ($id = 1000000; $id <= последний_номер_id; $id++) {
        $url = sprintf(
            "http://i01.fsimg.ru/%d/user_big/%s/%s/%d.jpg",
            $avatar,
            substr(strval($id),0,3), # первые 3 цифры номера
            substr(strval($id),0,5), # нервые 5 цифр номера
            $id # номер полностью
        );
    }
}
?>
проверил - не работает

Comment: @Семен, вам подсказали намного больше, чем было в вашем вопросе. Если вы php не понимаете вообще (о чем говорит скопированный вами код), вам на [free-lance.ru](http://www.free-lance.ru/). Цена такого скрипта - $10.

Comment: А я проверил свой скрипт который генерирует URL-и для `i01.fsimg.ru` и у меня все работает, опишите подробно какая возникает ошибка.